# How do I create a composite foreign key going backwards down a relationship?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Sorry about the title, couldn't think of a better way to write it.

Here's my problem...
I have 2 tables in my database [Drawings] and [Revisions];

```
[Drawings] 1-----* [Revisions]
 ProjectId(pk)      ProjectId(pk)(fk)
 DrawingNo(pk)      DrawingNo(pk)(fk)
                    RevisionNo(pk)
 LatestRevision
```

There is a foreign key in [revisions] referencing [drawings] on [ProjectId] and [DrawingNo].
I need to implement a way of enforcing that the drawings latest revision number equals a corresponding revision number in the revisions table:

```
... WHERE [Drawings].[LatestRevision] NOT IN (
        SELECT [RevisionNo] 
        FROM [Revisions] 
        WHERE [Drawings].[ProjectId] = [Revisions].[ProjectId]
        AND [Drawings].[DrawingNo] = [Revisions].[DrawingNo])
```

How would I put something like this into a foreign key?

I need this to work on sql server 2008 express onwards.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Schema:

```
TABLE Drawings
( ProjectId varchar,
  DrawingNo varchar,
  LatestRevisions varchar,
  ...other columns
  PRIMARY KEY(ProjectId, DrawingNo)
)

TABLE Revisions
( ProjectId varchar,
  DrawingNo varchar,
  RevisionNo varchar,
  ...other columns
  PRIMARY KEY(ProjectId, DrawingNo, RevisionNo)
  FOREIGN KEY(ProjectId, DrawingNo) REFERENCES (Drawings(ProjectId, DrawingNo))
)
```

Drawing 'A' can have revision '1', and Drawing 'B' can have a different revision '1',
Revision number by itself is not unique

Comment: Any statement that you issue that changes table state (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE) can only affect *one* table. And since SQL Server doesn't support deferred constraints, what you're asking for cannot be built - you always either a) have to insert into `Revisions` first, in which case `LatestRevision` is out of date, or b) have to update `Drawings` first in which case it references a row which doesn't actually (yet) exist. There are ways to ensure that `Revisions` always has a consistent set of revisions and the latest one is easy to find, if that interests you?

Answer (score 0):

I will take the schema as follows:

```
TABLE drawings
( projectid      integer,
  drawingno      integer,
  latestRevision integer,
  primary key (projectid, drawingno)
)

TABLE revisions
( revisionno     integer primary key,
  projectid      integer,
  drawingno      integer,
  foreign key (projectid, drawingno)
      references (drawings (projectid, drawingno))
)
```

In this case, I would issue:

```
ALTER TABLE drawings
ADD FOREIGN KEY (latestRevision)
REFERENCES (revisions(revisionNo))
```

This would mean that every `revisions.revisionNo` is unique and the column `drawings.latestRevision` is a foreign key that references the primary key of `revisions` table, that is, `revisionNo`.

Please let me know if there are any changes to the schema you have.

Also, the foreign key is enforced only if it is referencing a primary key of another table. If `revisions.revisionno` is not a primary key or if the primary key constraint is disabled on this column, then the `ALTER TABLE .. ADD FOREIGN KEY` statement is bound to return an error.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response Rachcha. Does that solution take into account that many drawings can have the same numbered revisions? For example, if drawing 'A' has revision '3', then will it allow drawing 'b' to have a latest revision '3' even though it doesn't have a revision '3' of it's own?!

Comment: Got an error: "There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.P75DocRev' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_P75Doc_LatestRevision'."

Comment: Do you really have `revisions.revisionNo` as the primary key?

Comment: Primary key is a composite of ProjectId, DrawingNo, RevisionNo, as shown in my crude depiction in my question (understandable if that wasn't clear).

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

The following structures replaces your tables with views and *looks* similar to what you describe, except it's instead maintained behind the scenes rather than being an explicit foreign key. I don't know what operations you'd want to support on `Revisions`, at the moment I only support `INSERT`:

```
create table dbo._Drawings (
    ProjectId int not null,
    DrawingId int not null,
    constraint PK_Drawings PRIMARY KEY (ProjectID,DrawingID)
)
go
create table dbo._Revisions (
    ProjectID int not null,
    DrawingID int not null,
    RevisionNo int not null,
    _PreviousRevision as CASE WHEN RevisionNo > 1 THEN RevisionNo - 1 END persisted,
    _NextRevision int null,
    constraint PK_Revisions PRIMARY KEY (ProjectID,DrawingID,RevisionNo),
    constraint FK_Revisions_Drawings FOREIGN KEY (ProjectID,DrawingID)
             references _Drawings (ProjectID,DrawingID),
    constraint CK_RevisionNos CHECK (RevisionNo >= 1),
    constraint UK_Revisions_Previous UNIQUE (ProjectID,DrawingID,_PreviousRevision),
    constraint UK_Revisions_Next UNIQUE (ProjectID,DrawingID,_NextRevision),
    constraint FK_Revisions_Previous FOREIGN KEY (ProjectID,DrawingID,_PreviousRevision)
             references _Revisions (ProjectID,DrawingID,RevisionNo),
    constraint FK_Revisions_Next FOREIGN KEY (ProjectID,DrawingID,_NextRevision) 
             references _Revisions (ProjectID,DrawingID,RevisionNo)
)
```

The above two tables are the "backing store" for the data. The `_Revisions` table ensures that the revision sequences are strictly monotonically increasing from 1. Each row maintains a foreign key to its immediate preceding and succeeding revisions, except the first and last, for which `NULL`s substitute (but the unique constraints ensure only one of each exists for each `ProjectID`,`DrawingID` combination.

```
create view dbo.Drawings
with schemabinding
as
    select
        d.ProjectID,
        d.DrawingID,
        r.RevisionNo as LatestRevision
    from
        dbo._Drawings d
            left join
        dbo._Revisions r
            on
                d.ProjectId = r.ProjectID and
                d.DrawingId = r.DrawingID and
                r._NextRevision is null
```

The above view mimics your asked for `Drawings` table and would be used for any actual data access. If you wanted to enforce an invariant that each drawing must have at least one revision, you could switch the `left join` to an `inner join` and make this an [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx). You'd need to add a trigger to support `INSERT`s, in much the same way as the below does for `Revisions`, which then populates both tables.

```
create view dbo.Revisions
with schemabinding
as
    select
        ProjectID,
        DrawingID,
        RevisionNo
    from
        dbo._Revisions
```

This view creates the impression that `Revisions` is as simple as in your query

```
create trigger T_Revisions_I
on dbo.Revisions
instead of insert
as
    ;with SplitData as (
        select ProjectID,DrawingID,RevisionNo,RevisionNo-1 as Prev, Seq
        from inserted cross join (select 1 union all select 2) t(Seq)
    )
    merge into dbo._Revisions r
    using SplitData s
    on
        r.ProjectID = s.ProjectID and
        r.DrawingID = s.DrawingID and
        (
            (s.Seq = 1 and r.RevisionNo = s.Prev) or
            (s.Seq = 2 and r.RevisionNo = s.RevisionNo)
        )
    when matched and s.Seq = 1
    then update set _NextRevision = s.RevisionNo
    when not matched and s.Seq = 2
    then insert (ProjectID,DrawingID,RevisionNo) values (s.ProjectID,s.DrawingID,s.RevisionNo)
    ;
```

And finally, this trigger is responsible for maintaining the `_Revisions` structure in the way that the constraints I created above require. The trick is that we use a [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement so that at the same time as we insert the new row, we also update the previous row so that it's `_NextRevision` column is no longer null and references the row that we're inserting.

More triggers can be added to support more advanced usage.

Comment: Hi Damien, thank you for the response. I think I understand what you've written, you're obviously way above me on db skills/knowledge! I believe that the solution would fail on the count that the drawingNo and revisionNo (as well as projectId) are varchars (sorry, I really should have said that to start with) and are not sequential in any way, the user enters whatever they want for those values. Am I right in saying that that messes up your answer?

Comment: @RazorUK84 - yes, part of a key reason to use such a structure was to be able to quickly identify the latest revision in the `_Revisions` table - and that relied on the `RevisionNo`s always being in numerical order with no gaps. Oh well :-(

Comment: Thanks anyway mate, I wish my database were better designed, but I'm dealing with a legacy db that I cannot change the core structure of unfortunately! :-(